# addColumn with select options in generated admin field

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, custom-options, custom-field

I want to know if someone has already added a select field in a generated admin fields

**Vendor/Name/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Field/AdditionalMenu.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Menu\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

/**
 * Class AdditionalMenu
 */
class AdditionalMenu extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    protected $_itemRenderer;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'Title',
            ['label' => __('Title'),
             'size' => '200px',
             'class' => 'required-entry']
        );
        //Option test
        /*$this->addColumn('Type',
        array('label'   => __('Type'),
              'type'    =>'options',
              'options' => array('Option 1', 'Option 2')
        ));*/
        $this->addColumn(
            'Link',
            ['label' => __('Link'),
             'size' => '200px']
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'Ordre',
            ['label' => __('Ordre'),
             'size' => '50px',
             'class' => '']
        );
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Ajouter un Menu');
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

**How to add a select options column :**

```
<?php    
namespace Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

/**
 * Class AdditionalEmail
 */
class AdditionalMenu extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    protected $_typeblockOptions;
    protected $_cmsblockOptions;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'attributname',
            [
                'label' => __('Attributname'),
                'size' => '200px',
                'renderer' => $this->_getGroupRenderer()]
        );

        //OR
        $this->addColumn(
            'title',
            [
                'label' => __('Titre'),
                'size' => '200px',
                'class' => 'required-entry']
        );

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Ajouter un Menu');

protected function _getGroupRenderer()
{
    if (!$this->_cmsblockOptions) {
        $this->_cmsblockOptions = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend\Options::class,
            '',
            ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
        );
        $this->_cmsblockOptions->setClass('attributname_group_select');
    }
    return $this->_cmsblockOptions;
}
```

**Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend\Options.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend;

class Options extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value);
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = '<select>';
        $html .= '<option value="First">First value</option>';
        $html .= '<option value="Second">Second value</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me _cmsblockOptions about this function i am getting error that function not found

Comment: @Arunendra I updated a file

Comment: how to add a dynamic id and name for the select dropdown. rite now the following code doesnt save the data.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above answer, u can also just overwrite the `getOptions` Method from the extended `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select` and return the `toOptionArray` Method of an existing SourceModel. Incase u just want to have a select inside of an `AbstractFieldArray` that is based on a SourceModel.

For example the Yesno Sourcemodel:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno as YesnoSource;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select;

/**
 * Class YesNo
 * @package Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field
 */
class Yesno extends Select
{
    /**
     * @var YesnoSource
     */
    protected $yesnoSource;

    /**
     * YesNo constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param YesnoSource $yesnoSource
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        YesnoSource $yesnoSource,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->yesnoSource = $yesnoSource;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|void
     */
    public function getOptions()
    {
        return $this->yesnoSource->toOptionArray();
    }
}
```

Which is pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

Researching some magento 2 documentation I find this, I think it might help you guys
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [PЯINCƎ](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/48355/p%D0%AFinc%C6%8E)'s [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/224482/110912):
for adding dynamic id and name to the select element, change code from

```
    $html = '<select>';
```

to

```
    $html = '<select id="' . $this->getInputId() . '" name="' . $this->getName() . '">';
```